# javascript event bubbling : with styling color

Tags: javascript, events, event-bubbling

i was just checking the event bubbling with different html styles and i came across the color change in div element.

in the for loop the color in all three div elements changes to yellow irrespective of the div element clicked while the border color is being change as the event bubbling scenario but it's not working with the color thing., can you explain this why is it happening?﻿

Here's my code:

```
var divelements = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(var i= 0 ; i< divelements.length; i++)
{
    divelements[i].onclick = function ()
    {
        this.style.borderColor = 'red';
        this.style.color = 'yellow';
        alert(this.getAttribute("id") + 'is changed to color red');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `this.style.backgroundColor` instead of `this.style.color`.